# Portlet in Websphere 6 to Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: websphere, jboss7.x, portlet, gatein

I'm looking for some tutorials about portlet in internet, but i can't find a good one. I need to migrate a portlet deployed in websphere 6 to jboss 7, i have some questions about it and i hope you can help me

1. is it possible migrate a portlet from websphere to jboss 7? I understand that you need a portlet container and i can't find that reference in jboss 7
2. I found in jboss page a project called GateIn, that looks like be a portlet container, is this correct?
3. A portlet developed in websphere can migrate to other application server without modification in your code?
4. None of my co-workers know about portlet, and because the few examples in internet, i think this is a almost deprecated solution, is this correct?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. Portlets are defined in a JSR specification (v1 is JR-168 and v2 ios JSR-286). Which means as long you have a portlet that complies with spec, you should be able to move it to any portlet container that complies with the spec.

2) Yes, GateIn is a portlet container.

3) As long as the portlet isn't calling any WebSphere specific API calls, you should be able to move it to another portlet container.

4) Portlets are far from deprecated. There are multiple portlet containers (WebSphere Portal, Liferay, GateIn and still a few more). Many of these containers still receive frequent updates and are being deployed for new websites.

There should be a sufficient amount of tutorials / discussion around the web if that's what you mean by "examples". Even looking on SO, you can find new portlet questions.

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes this is possible, the only requirement you have is that your portlet should be a JSR168/286 compliant ().
2- Yes gatein is the eXo&Jboss Portal including a Portlet Container.
3- Yes, if it is a JSR 168/286 compliant portlet and  does not depend on a Websphere API 
4- No, there are many products using Portlet technologies like Gatein, eXo Platform or Liferay

Here are some portlet samples that could help you https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal/tree/3.5.x/examples/portlets